# ActivatedRouteSnapshot not showing all data

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having quite a headache because of the following. Hope you can point me in the right direction.

I'm working with Angular 2's ActivatedRouteSnapshot from angular/router in a custom Guard. The route where this guard is called has different data from a resolver. However when I try to access this data, this data is not found, but it is there. Let me clarify with a real example:

**app.routing**

```
(...)
path: "businessrules", component: TabsComponent, data: { title: "Business Rules Configuration" }, canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard], resolve: {
                environmentsList: EnvironmentsResolver,
                pagesList: PagesResolver
            }
(...)
```

**role-guard.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
}
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    console.log(route); //here, inside route, you can find data, and inside it, environmentList and pagesList
    console.log(route.data); //but here, this data can't be found
    return true;
    }
}
```

**console.log(route)**

```
(...)
Object: 
    environmentsList:Array[4]
    pagesList:Array[6]
    title: "Business Rules Configuration"
    __proto__:Object
(...)
```

**console.log(route.data)**

```
(...)
Object
    title: "Business Rules Configuration"
    __proto__: Object
(...)
```

Both logs are for the same route, so, am I missing something?
Sorry if the post is a bit messy, gladly will try to clarify if something is weird.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
A colleague told me I needded to subscribe to route.data, but it seems I can't subscribe nor map an ActivatedRouteSnapshot, only a ActivatedRoute. Also, the method canActivate requires ActivatedRouteSnapshot, so I can't use ActivatedRoute, and I can't use ActivatedRoute in the constructor as it will only be executed once and I need it to be executed per route.
Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was also stuck with similar problem.

I have a workaround see if that helps your purpose and those who come looking for similar problem.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    window.location.href = route.root.children[0].routeConfig.resolve.url;
    return true;
}
```

it is available under **route.root.children[i].routeConfig.resolve**

I couldn't get data but passing the resolve in route served the purpose.

```
resolve: {
    url: "<myurl>"
}
```